# Using physical disks from old RAID NAS

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, raid, sata, nas

I had a WD MyCloud EX4100 NAS device with four 4TB SATA disks configured in a RAID 5 array (so, 16TB capacity, less overhead).

A lightning strike rendered the device inoperable. It will not boot.

The insurance company has replaced the NAS device with a new one. It is identical in every way (except perhaps firmware level), as the old device was only a year or so old.

I would like to replace the four blank disks in the new device with the four disks from the old one. I am assuming that the existing disks were not damaged by the lightning strike, only the NAS electronics.

Of course, I will respect the positioning of the physical drives in the array -- I'll put the drive from old slot 1 into new slot 1, etc.

If my assumption is correct that the physical drives were not damaged, should I be able to access my data on the new NAS device? Are there any settings I should make or other procedures I should follow before transferring the drives?

For bonus credit: To maximize the selling price, should I sell the four new, blank drives separately, or as a set of four?

Comment: As far as I know RAID is depending on the Hardware and Firmware of the Controller. As you said the hardware is identical, only the firmware may have change. In this case i would say you could have luck an all will fit without problems. Regarding the drives: I think selling them separately will bring you more money, but I would keep at least one drive as spare.

Comment: Make an image of all the drives first, then put them back in the new enclosure in the same order and see if it recovers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. Migrating physical disks from one WD MyCloud 4100 enclosure to another is a supported process called RAID Roaming. The steps to follow are detailed [here](https://support.wdc.com/knowledgebase/answer.aspx?ID=17087), in an official WD support article.

I followed the steps, and everything worked fine. All my old partitions and data are visible. I just had to update the firmware settings to match what I had before -- set the device name, set users and permissions, things like that.